# Как правильно совместить jquery и angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Стоит задача разработать крупное одностраничное приложение на Angular. При этом избегаю использования jQuery. Но на одной "странице" используется редактор WYSIWYG Imperavi, который написан на jQuery. Отказаться от использования этого редактора нельзя (по причинам не зависящим от меня). Вопрос в том, как в данном случае правильно использовать библиотеку jQuery. Можно ли как-то подгружать ее динамически, или же придется ради одной малопосещаемой страницы подключать jQuery для всего сайта?

Comment: Очевидно, её можно подключить только на этой странице.

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Ммм... Берешь страничку с редактором и подключаешь на ней jquery. А потом берешь остальные странички сайта и не подключаешь к ним jquery.

Comment: Я честно не понимаю, в чем проблема.

Comment: Речь об одностраничном приложении на angular

Comment: А, одностраничное (прошу прощения). Тогда да, подключать сразу. Ну, то есть, можно загрузить её только когда пользователь откроет конкретно то, где оно нужно, но смысла особого нет.

Comment: Дело в том, что на страницу с редактором зайдет меньше 1% от всех посетителей сайта, поэтому смысл загружать ее только в этом случае есть. Вопрос в том, как это сделать.

Comment: Гугл с ходу выдает вот это: https://github.com/urish/angular-load
Думаю, если не нужна вся функциональность, можно вырезать только нужную (там скриптик-то маленький)

Comment: Если нужно использовать jQuery плагины в Angular, то чаще всего их оборачивают в директиву. Но это не всегда так просто, т.к. нужно уметь правильно уничтожить плагин после использования, следить за событиями и биндингами. Если [это](https://imperavi.com/redactor/) редактор, о котором вы говорите, то похоже что для него уже есть директива - [angular-redactor](https://github.com/TylerGarlick/angular-redactor) - которая оборачивает плагин.

Comment: Не стоит париться на этот счет, собирайте проект вместе с jquery. 80Kb сегодня не так много :) Это хорошая практика

Answer (score 1):

В чём проблема подключить jquery на странице? - он вроде небольшой и проще его подключить для всей страницы и обработать при загрузке приложения чем подгружать динамически в темплейте страницы с WYSIWYG (я так понял вы именно это имеете ввиду под "страницей")

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с v1.4.0-beta.6, Angular имеет встроенную поддержку ngJq:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngJq